# Inspiron 5558, install another OS alongside Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, dell

i have the DELL inspiron 5558 ubuntu 14 version. I am happy with is but i do need to install as well some other OSes.
i do need to install win7, freebsd as well with ubuntu which is currently working. In order to fix MBR i will boot from live cd to fix it after finishing the install of the other OSes. i have already squeezed the partitions to make space. Ubuntu runs on a total of 50GB. I am stuck with the partitioning.
 Which partitions do i have to leave intact so i could restore the system?

Answer (score 0):

When editing partitions you can only expand partitions in front to absorb un-allocated space behind it. You can move partitions forwards or backgrounds. It's best to back up your files before doing the next part.

If you boot Ubuntu from a CD or USB there is an app installed, called GParted (I assume you know that because you know to boot it from a CD or USB, but I'll explain it just in case). Run that. I would suggest leaving the recovery partitions alone (I don't know what these are called, I'm not on a Dell computer--Also, those are the ones you should leave alone). These are used for the computer saving OS's if they stop working properly. You can make partitions larger only if they're in the front, so make sure whichever ones you want to use are moved to the front.

When I did this, it took me doing this two or three times before it actually worked, so try a few times before giving up. Good luck!